# Haskell- Is string only composed of characters from another string

Tags: haskell

I want to check if a string given by the user is only composed from characters of another string previously given as program arguments

I have search every where for doing this in haskell but I didn't found anything (found answer for other language but not haskell)
I know how to do this in python or in C but this is my first haskell program

Here is what I have so far :

I'm calling the function + setup of the string to check

```
myCheck first second = do
-- some stuff
let alpha = "01" -- normally this is given with argument by the user but just for simplicity let's do it that way (it could also be alpha = "aziuefè!çè")
suite <- getLine
if isValid suite alpha
  then putStr "OK\n"
  else exit
-- some other stuff
```

Now the Is valid function the isValid "" alpha = True is important because I need to handle that elsewhere later in the code

```
isValid :: String -> String -> Bool                                                                       
isValid "" alpha = True                                                                                   
isValid xs alpha =                                                                                      
  case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of                                                                  
    "" -> True                                                                                             
   ('.':ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)                                                                  
   _ -> False
```

And the isAlphabet function

```
isAlphabet :: Char -> String -> Bool                                                                     
isAlphabet xs alpha = xs `elem` alpha
```

But (and I'm starting to get used to while using haskell)

```
 /Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:29:19: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
• Possible cause: ‘isAlphabet’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the first argument of ‘dropWhile’, namely
    ‘(isAlphabet xs alpha)’
  In the expression: dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha)
  In the expression:
    case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
      "" -> True
      ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
      _ -> False
     |
  29 |   case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
     |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:29:30: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: Char
    Actual type: String
• In the first argument of ‘isAlphabet’, namely ‘xs’
  In the first argument of ‘dropWhile’, namely
    ‘(isAlphabet xs alpha)’
  In the expression: dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha)
   |
29 |   case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
   |                              ^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:30:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
              with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: ""
     In a case alternative: "" -> True
     In the expression:
    case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
      "" -> True
      ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
      _ -> False
   |
30 |     "" -> True
   |     ^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:31:6: error:
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
               with actual type ‘[Char]’
 • In the pattern: '.' : ys
  In a case alternative: ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
  In the expression:
    case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
      "" -> True
      ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
      _ -> False
   |
31 |     ('.':ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |      ^^^^^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:31:17: error:
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
              with actual type ‘t0 a1 -> Bool’
  • Probable cause: ‘all’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
  In a case alternative: ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
  In the expression:
    case dropWhile (isAlphabet xs alpha) of
      "" -> True
      ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
      _ -> False
   |
31 |     ('.':ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:31:22: error:
   • Couldn't match expected type ‘a1 -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
   • Possible cause: ‘isAlphabet’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the first argument of ‘all’, namely ‘(isAlphabet ys alpha)’
    In the expression: all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
    In a case alternative: ('.' : ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |
31 |     ('.':ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:31:33: error:
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
  • In the first argument of ‘isAlphabet’, namely ‘ys’
    In the first argument of ‘all’, namely ‘(isAlphabet ys alpha)’
    In the expression: all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |
31 |     ('.':ys) -> all (isAlphabet ys alpha)
   |                                 ^^
```

This specific function isn't homework but part of a bigger project that is
Thank you, really hope I didn't miss any previous questions already answered

Edit suggested by answer :

Removed isAlphabet (this function wasn't making any sense, since it was only calling elem)

```
isValid :: String -> String -> Bool                                                                    
isValid "" alpha = True                                                                              
isValid xs alpha =                                                                                         
  case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of                                                                      
    "" -> True                                                                                             
    ('.':ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys                                                                      
    _ -> False
```

compile errors :

```
/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:26:19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • Possible cause: ‘elem’ is applied to too many arguments
     In the first argument of ‘dropWhile’, namely ‘(xs `elem` alpha)’
      In the expression: dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha)
      In the expression:
        case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of
          "" -> True
         ('.' : ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys
         _ -> False
   |
26 |   case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:26:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [String]
        Actual type: String
    • In the second argument of ‘elem’, namely ‘alpha’
      In the first argument of ‘dropWhile’, namely ‘(xs `elem` alpha)’
      In the expression: dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha)
   |
26 |   case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of
   |                             ^^^^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:27:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: ""
      In a case alternative: "" -> True
      In the expression:
        case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of
          "" -> True
          ('.' : ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys
          _ -> False
   |
27 |     "" -> True
   |     ^^

/Users/mgial/tech2/FUN_deBruijn_2017/app/Main.hs:28:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: '.' : ys
      In a case alternative: ('.' : ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys
      In the expression:
        case dropWhile (xs `elem` alpha) of
          "" -> True
          ('.' : ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys
          _ -> False
   |
28 |     ('.':ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys
   |      ^^^^^^
```

Final edit :

```
isValid :: String -> String -> Bool                                                                     
isValid "" alpha = True                                                                                 
isValid xs alpha =                                                                                         
  case dropWhile (`elem` alpha) xs of                                                                      
    "" -> True                                                                                             
    ('.':ys) -> all (`elem` alpha) ys                                                                      
    _ -> False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `all (isAlphabet ys alpha)`, you try to first apply `isAlphabet` to *the entire string* `ys` and the alphabet, and then somehow pull the result of that through `all`. But, the types don't support this:

```
isAlphabet :: Char -> String -> Bool
               │         │       │
ys      ::   String      │       │
alpha   ::            String     │
all     ::                   (a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

What you instead want to do is *use* `all` to apply `isAlphabet` to each character *individually*. That's what it's there for.

```
  ... all (\c -> isAlphabet c alpha) ys ...
```

Note that if you'd defined the `isAlphabet` function which swapped arguments (which would be the more natural order) then you could shorten (eta-reduce) this to

```
isAlphabet :: String -> Char -> Bool

  ... all (isAlphabet alpha) ys ...
```

Alternatively you can use an *operator section* to directly apply the second argument. In fact I wouldn't bother defining `isAlphabet` in the first place, because it's actually an exact synonym for `elem`. Just write

```
  ... all (`elem` alpha) ys ...
```

```
all           :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
                     │         │
(`elem`alpha) :: Char->Bool    │
ys            ::             String
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, So I edtied the code accordingly to your suggestions but i'm still getting some compile errors. At least The "all" line looks fine. I've edited my question for more info

Comment: Well, it's basically the same issue with `dropWhile`.

Comment: Ok I think I got it thank, i'm gonna try some things then mark your answer as accepted, thanks again